# Vim not displaying Input mode (14.04)

Tags: vim, vi

When I open up the Vim editor, it's supposed to show at the bottom of the screen whether I'm in Input mode or not. But it stays blank whether I'm in Command mode or in Input mode.

Also, vimtutor doesn't work. All I get is a blank screen without any instructions.

It's the same whether I open up a terminal or use a virtual console.

Any ideas what might be wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From your experience with `vimtutor`, it looks like you have the basic version of `vim` installed (`vim-tiny`). It is just a step above the old school `vi` in the e**vi**lutionary ladder, so try installing a more feature-complete version:

```
sudo apt-get install vim
```

Or, to get GVim as well:

```
sudo apt-get install vim-gnome
```

And do remember to call `vim` instead of `vi`. If you still can't see the status indicator, enable `showmode`:

```
:set showmode
```

Comment: @ChristopherK., please look at http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers