# Show insert/command in vi

Tags: command-line, vi

I remember somehow being able to show at the bottom of the screen that I am in --insert-- or I am in command mode. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: Already answered here http://askubuntu.com/questions/612683/vim-not-displaying-input-mode-14-04

Comment: I don't want to get vim

Comment: That's what you use anyway. `vi` is a link to `vim` or `vim-tiny`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's the showmode option:

```
:set showmode
```

To make it permanent, create or modify your `$HOME/.vimrc` file and add the previously mentioned command in it, without the colon:

```
set showmode
```

Comment: It's temporary. How do I make it perma

Answer (score 0):

He's right. Another way to do so is with "cat":

```
cat "set showmode" >> ~/.vimrc
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: `echo` would be a better command to append. `cat` is meant to concatenate files.